# n layers vs mvc architecture - when using those architecture ?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, n-layer

I maked many reasearch about those two architectures but i could not choose which one to use . So  there is my  question : what is the  main  the advantages and the disadvantages  of the two architectures and  when  we use n layers instead of mvc architecture  ?

Comment: MVC is a GUI architecture only

Comment: All of architecture styles are not mutually exclusive. You have client-servers, n-tiers, mvc and soa in the same system simultaneously. And as it already had been said, MVC in general belongs to user-interaction layer.

Comment: You can use MVC pattern in an N-tier or onion architecture. First describe your requirements, how can you decide about architecture without them?

Answer (score 0):

N-tier and 3-tier are architectural deployment styles that describe the separation of functionality into segments in much the same way as the layered style, but with each segment being a tier that can be located on a physically separate computer.

Model-View-Controller. Separate the UI code into three separate units: Model (data), View (interface), and Controller (processing logic), with a focus on the View.

These patterns focus on separation of concerns for different perspectives. The n-tier focuses on the physical separation of components (client, server etc), while the MVC focuses on the UI component separation (graphics, processing logic etc).

As the other responses indicate, these are not mutually exclusive.